# Use reverse geocoding to get an adress as variable

Tags: html, javascript, geocoding

I am trying to make it so when a truck driver presses a button when he starts for the day, i can see what his location is at that very moment so i know where my drivers are starting from.

I am trying to get it so when someone gives acces to their location you can get a straight adress out of it as a variable. it just needs to be city and a country.

like this: Nottingham, NG1 1AJ, UK

Here the link as an example of how it should turn out: https://www.mapdevelopers.com/what-is-my-address.php

i can only find reverse geocoding where it just shows the location on the map.  i am trying to get it as a variable output to show in an app. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is this button they are pressing?